# Have there been any other attempts to axiomatize/mathematize a model of an economy from the ground up like Debreu's Theory of Value

Tags: mathematical-economics, reference-request, general-equilibrium

I'm looking for other attempts to axiomatize/mathematize the model of an economy from the ground up, into a sort of a long-winded general mathematical model, as it is done in Debreu's Theory of Value. Are there any other such examples in economics?

Comment: Most modern advanced textbooks of microeconomics do that.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Could you provide examples of such textbooks, please?

Comment: Standard textbooks covering this model are, for example, "Microeconomic Theory" by Mas-Colell, Whinston, Green, or "Microeconomic Foundations I" by David Kreps.

Comment: Almost any graduate text on microeconomics is axiomatized and starts with much of Debreu's theory (existence of utility representations of preferences, equivalence between choice, preferences, and utility etc) along with basic consumer and producer theory which follow directly from this foundational material. The only mainstream exception I think of is Chicago Price Theory, written by Kevin Murphy and others.